# Conditional Probability with Density Function

Tags: probability, density-function

Let the density of random variable $X$ be given as 
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} 12x^2 & -0.5 \le x \le 0.5 \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

How can I determine $$f_X(x\mid-0.25 \le X \le 0.25)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way: apply conditional probability.

$$f_X(x\mid a\leq X\leq b) ~=~\dfrac{~ f_X(x)~\mathbf 1_{a\leq x\leq b}~}{~\displaystyle\int_a^b f_X(s)\operatorname d s~}$$

---

PS: $\mathbf 1_{a\leq x\leq b}$ is an indicator.

$$\mathbf 1_{a\leq x\leq b}=\begin{cases} 1 & : a\leq x\leq b \\[1ex] 0 & : \textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$